# Error in the book? Or wrong logic?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the book "Elementary linear algebra with supplemental applications", 11th edition, page 81,task 127, the following task appears:

> Show that if $A$ is a square matrix such that $A^K=0$ for some positive integer $K$, then the matrix $A$ is invertible and the inverse of the matrix $(I-A)$ is equal to $I + A + A^2 + ... + A^{K-1}$.

I have no difficulty in arriving at the identity given that $A^K = 0$, however I think there is something wrong here... Consider the following:

Let $A$ be a square matrix **not equal to 0**, such that $A^K=0$ for some nonnegative integer $K \ge 2$, and assume for contradiction that $A^{-1}$ exists. Then we can deduce the following:

$$A^K=0 \implies A^K A^{-1}=0 \implies A^{K-1} A A^{-1} = 0 \implies A^{K-1} I = 0$$

and we are left with $A^{K-1} = 0$.

Thus, $A^K=0 \implies A^{K-1} = 0$, and using the same logic (multiplying by $A^{-1}$), we deduce $A^K=0 \implies A^{K-1} = 0 \implies \cdots \implies A^2 = 0 \implies A = 0$, a contradiction. Thus, the three statements "$A$ does not equal $0$", "$A^{-1}$ exists" and "$A^K=0$ for some nonnegative integer $K$ greater than or equal to $2$" cannot all be true at the same time. And thus the task in the book is inncorrect since it states that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Is the book wrong, or is there something wrong with my use of logic here? :)

Comment: If that's what the book says, it's wrong. It should say $I-A$ is invertible.

Comment: Since this is about the inverse of $I-A$, I guess it's a simple typo, and the sentence should read "Show that if $A$ is a square matrix such that $A^K=0$ for some positive integer $K$, then the matrix $I-A$ is invertible and the inverse of the matrix $(I-A)$ is equal to $I + A + A^2 + ... + A^(K-1) $".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem should be to prove $I-A$ is invertible.  If $A^k=0$, the determinant of $A^k$ is zero, so the determinant of $A$ is also zero, so $A$ is not invertible.  Then the equation to be proved should remind you of the sum of a geometric series.  Just multiply $(I-A)(I+A+A^2+\ldots A^{K-1})$ and most of the terms cancel.

Comment: I invoke the spirit of Sheldon Axler:  you do not need a determinant to show that $A$ is not invertible.  Simply observe that if $A$ where invertible, then it would have trivial kernel. So if $v$ is nonzero, $A(v)$ is as well.  But then $A^2(v)$ is also nonzero.  Continuing inductively we can see that $A^n(v)$ is never equal to zero, if $v$ was nonzero.  However, $A^k(v) = 0$, which is a contradiction.  So $A$ must have been singular all along.

Comment: Determinant approach is a lot shorter though.

Comment: @Math_QED: Short determinant-free approach: If $A$ is invertible then $A^{-1}$ exists, so $A^{-k}$ exists, so $I=A^{-k}A^k=0$, contradiction.

Comment: @Math_QED The product of invertible matrices is invertible.

Answer (score 5):

If $A^k=O$ then $A^{-1}$ does not exist. I believe the author intended to say $I-A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is not necessarily invertible. Consider $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A^2=0$ but $A$ is not invertible. The statement has to be $I-A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the $A$ is invertible then $A^k$ must be invertible. To see this just compute the determinant of $A^k$.

A possible correction to the book is to show that $(I-A)$ is invertible.